differential entropy for comparison distributions
I want to use differential entropy to compare the outcome of Bayesian updating (multidimensional probability distributions) for different datasets. My parameters are different physical parameters i.e. the have different dimensions and (very) different absolute values.
Now, I’m wondering if differential entropy is a good measure for comparison.
Can it occur that e.g. differential entropy decreases only because a certain variable (with high absolute values) becomes (a little) more precisely determined while another variable is less well defined, only because one variable has high absolute values?
In this case, the information / approximation would not be well described by this measure, as increasing knowledge of a parameter with high absolute value would seem to improve knowledge of the multidimensional distribution on the cost of another parameter that is equally important but has a lower range of absolute values.

So you want to compare the (multidimensional) probability distributions of your parameter vector, is that correct?

Yes! (There are several parameters, so it is rather describes as a matrix)

Yes, I suspect that this can easily happen. For example, let's say the distribution you get is a centered two-dimensional normal distribution with no correlation. The differential entropy of such a distribution is
$$
\frac{1}{2}\log \left( (2\pi e)^2 \det(\Sigma) \right) = \frac{1}{2} \left( \log(2\pi e)^2 + \log \sigma_1^2 + \log \sigma_2^2 \right)
$$
where $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ are the standard deviations of dimensions 1 and 2, respectively. We can see immediately, that the value of the differential entropy is dominated by the larger $\log\sigma_i^2$ term if there are substantial differences between the standard deviations.
I doubt that this behaviour is limited to Gaussian distributions. You could do some simulation experiments to verify that and see how much this affects comparison in your application.
